# UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity gives user name or password incorrect exception

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to connect to AD using PrincipalContext and admin credentials. After the connectivity is done i am validating user credentails. Once the user credentials are validated i am using UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity which always throws an exception "user name or password is incorrect".
Below is my code

```
PrincipalContext pricipalContext = null;
pricipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.ApplicationDirectory, server, userdomainLdappath, "adminUsername", "adminPassword");
pricipalContext.ValidateCredentials("clientUsername", "clientPassword");
UserPrincipal usp = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pricipalContext, "clientUsername");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that `ValidateCredentials` uses the client credentials to connect to AD (that's how it validates). So your `FindByIdentity` line is the first time `adminUsername`/`adminPassword` are validated. So I suspect your admin credentials may be incorrect.